# get first element selected in options Material-UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello guys I'm using React Material UI select. When I change option I trigger onChange method and add attr on selected value so how can I set fisrt option of items as selected.

```
       value={} **// I want to display first option to selected without trigger on Change method**
       onChange={(e) => {
            data.forEach(a => {
            if (a.Id === e.target.value) {
                 a.selected = true
               } else {
                 a.selected = false
               }
            });
       }}
     >
         <MenuItem disabled value=""><em>Please Select</em></MenuItem>
         {data.map((item) => {
               return (
                 <MenuItem key={item.Id} value={item.Id} >
                       {item.Ad}
                 </MenuItem>
               );
         })}
     </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 states on your component, `data` and `active`. Where `data` is the items you want to display on the dropdown, and `active` which indicates what item is currently selected. Commonly, we use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to initialize states.

Also, wehave to re-implement your `onChange` function. I suggest you review the docs on how to update states on functional component https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate.

---

Anyway, you can change your code to this

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(DATA);

  // select the first option by default
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(DATA[0].Id);

  function onChange(event) {
    setActive(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <Select value={active} onChange={onChange} fullWidth>
      <MenuItem disabled value="">
        <em>Please Select</em>
      </MenuItem>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <MenuItem key={item.Id} value={item.Id}>
          {item.Ad}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

...and I created a codesandbox for you to try it out.

[image: Edit charming-dewdney-llw8r]